# Why does everything deserve a nickname in A Song of Ice and Fire?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

I've read the entire series so far and was wondering if anyone else noticed that many people have really cool nick names - usually containing the word "The".

For example:

- Sandor Clegane is **The Hound**
- **Bronze** Yohn Royce
- **The Red Viper** of Dorne
- Tyrion is **The Imp**
- ... on and on...

The effect isn't just limited to people's names either.  For example:

> When the sickness that hits Meereen arrives with from someone on a pale horse, the sickness earned the nickname "The Pale Mare"

Don't get me wrong - I think they are very cool.  But It just seems odd that almost everyone has a nick name!

Anyone else notice this?  Is there a reason other than "it is cool to have a nick name"?

Comment: This reads a lot like a discussion-disguised-as-a-question to me.  Could you perhaps focus in on something more specific relating to some of the nicknames?

Comment: @JimmyShelter That wouldn't be the point.  I want to know if anyone knows the reason for the abundance of nicknames, not details on a few.

Comment: @Trenin I take you want to know if there is an in-universe reason?

Comment: Nicknames are just common. Even in real life. Many European surnames used to be nicknames before they were made official surnames.

Comment: I would say that for every nickname, there is 10 people without a nickname: Mikken, Joseth, Old Nan, Hodor, Harwin, Hullen, Jory, Rodrik, Maester Luwen, Meera and Jojen Reed, Osha, Asha, Theon, Victarion, Balon, Tywin, Tytos, Kevan, Tygett, Tyrek, Willem, Martyn, Lancel, Joffrey, Myrcella, Tommen, Jon, Robb, Rickon, Sansa, Arya, Brandon, Lyanna, Benjen, Eddard, Howland, Roose, Ramsay, Catelyn, Lysa, Hoster, Edmure, Arianne, Quentyn, Trystane, the sandsnakes: Obara, Nymeria, Tyene, Sarella, Rhaegar Targaryen, Arys Oakheart, Meryn Trant, Boros Blount, Aron Santagar, Preston Greenfield, etc.

Comment: @TLP Lots of those have nicknames.  Off the top of my head: Robb - Young Wolf, Old Nan is a nickname (Nan is her name, so Old Nan is a nickname), Jon - Lord Snow, Ramsay - The Bastard of Bolton, Catelyn - Lady Stoneheart, Theon - Turncloak, the sandsnakes are a collective nickname.

Comment: @MPelletier I like this answer.

Comment: @Trenin I mentioned 60 names, 6 had nicknames -- point in case.

Comment: @TLP Sorry.  I assumed your original list was meant to be a list of people you thought did not have nicknames.  I was not aware that you intentionally hid 6 people with nicknames in that list.

Comment: @Trenin It was, I don't agree about the nicknames, I am just conceding a point for a larger one: That most people do not have nicknames.

Comment: Take a look at this list: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/List_of_Characters - almost 200 characters have a nickname important enough to be referenced there.  Granted, there are about 2000 names in that list, but the VAST majority of those are irrelevant characters.  Having a fantasy series with 200 characters having a well deserved moniker seems odd.

Comment: @Trenin Did you really count? :) Well, I don't know, never really thought about it. When I do, it seems that as you say important characters tend to have them more often (which makes sense), and that many of the Night's watch men have them (Dolorous Edd, Halfhand, Old Bear, Toad, Small Paul, Stonesnake, etc). And also perhaps the Winterfell men (Fat Tom, Alebelly, Poxy Tim, etc). I guess it is a way to make a character more important and more memorable. And, as you say, more cool.

Comment: @TLP No - I used regular expressions.  Searched for "called" "known as" or quotes in the lines.  Gives a rough estimate.

Comment: @TLP That doesn't include ones whose names are obviously made up, but we don't know their real names.  For example, from the B's - Biter, Big Boil, Blind Doss.

Comment: @Trenin: I assume you come from a culture/country where people don't have nicknames? At school, the majority of people I know (including myself) had nicknames (>50%). So I never even gave the nicknames in GOT a second thought. In my family, about 1 in 10 have nicknames. Also, 100% of people have honorary titles which act as nicknames (calling your uncle by his name is considered rude but in Malay culture you wouldn't call him by a generic "uncle" either. Your eldest aunt or uncle would be called mak/pak loong. Your second eldest uncle would be called pak ngah etc.).

Comment: Note that my nikname on stackexchange is actually a slight modification of my nickname at school and some of my friends actually call me "slebetman" instead of my real name.

Comment: @slebetman Good point.  However, I was more confused by the number of nicknames sound very important and unique (usually containing "THE").  For example, "The Red Viper of Dorne" sounds like a very important and imposing name.  In real life, there are very few people who get a "THE" in their nickname.  Those who try are usually doing so in jest or come off sounding obnoxious.
Also, the feather that broke the proverbial camel's back for me was when the disease that spread through Meereen also got an important nickname - The Pale Mare.

Comment: @Trenin - like The Black Death?

Comment: @Davor Sure, but the Black Death was a huge disease that killed millions, "one of the most devastating pandemics in human history" (wikipedia).  As such, it deserves a nickname.  The disease in Meereen affected one city, and only because they were under siege.  During peace time, it would have been a non-event.  So does it deserve its own name?  Was it the only one of its kind, and thus deserving of a "The"?  I personally don't think so, which is part of the reason I asked this question.

Comment: The inhabitants of Westeros don’t have Candy Crush or Netflix to fill the long empty years before death (all 26 of them on average, probably), so they’ve got to entertain themselves somehow.